# XPath 2.0: Find all descendants matching criteria X, but with no ancestor matching criteria Y

Tags: xml, xpath-2.0

Given the xml:

```
<div itemtype="..." itemscope value="root">
  <div itemprop="..." value="1" /> <!-- want this -->
  <div value="2">
    <div itemprop="..." value="3" /> <!-- and this -->
  </div>
  <div itemtype="..." itemscope itemprop="..." value="4"> <!-- and even this -->
    <div itemprop value="5" /> <!-- but not this -->
    <div value="6" >
      <div itemprop value="7" > <!-- nor this -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to build an xpath query that returns all descendants of the root, which have an `itemprop` attribute, but are not descendants of a "nested" element with the `itemscope` attribute.
That is, I want all of the the root's properties, but not properties within nested scopes.
I'm fairly convinced this cannot be done in XPath 1.0. My naive attempt: `/descendant::*[not(@itemscope)]//*[@itemprop]` returns all `itemprop`'ed elements that have some ancestor with no `itemscope` attribute

EDIT: I need a general enough solution, that will work for fetching the `itemprops` in every level of the doc, not just the root. e.g., in my example, fetching the properties of "d"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use this XPath 1.0 expression**:

```
//*[@itemprop and not(ancestor::*[parent::* and @itemscope])]
```

This selects all elements with an `itemprop` attribute that don't have an ancestor with an `itemscope` attribute, that (this ancestor) has a parent element (this means it isn't the document-element itself).

In order to verify the exactly the wanted elements are selected, use this slightly modified expression (the modification makes it an XPath 2.0 expression):

```
//*[@itemprop and not(ancestor::*[parent::* and @itemscope])]/@value/string()
```

this produces the string value of the `value` attribute of every selected element.

**When the above XPath expression is evaluated** on this source XML document (the provided one, but corrected to make it a well-formed XML document:

```
<div itemtype="..." itemscope="x" value="root">
  <div itemprop="..." value="1" /> <!-- want this -->
  <div value="2">
    <div itemprop="..." value="3" /> <!-- and this -->
  </div>
  <div itemtype="..." itemscope="x" itemprop="..." value="4"> <!-- and even this -->
    <div itemprop="..." value="5" /> <!-- but not this -->
    <div value="6" >
      <div itemprop="..." value="7" /> <!-- nor this -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
1 3 4
```

Answer (score 1):

How about `//div[not(ancestor::div[ancestor::div[./@itemscope]]/@itemscope)]/@itemprop`

reading: all div's that don't have an ancestor with `itemscope`, who himself has an `itemscope` ancestor, get itemprop attribute

I had to make some changes, cause your XML is not really XML compliant:

```
<root>
    <div itemtype="a" itemscope="" value="root">
        <div itemprop="b" value="1" />
        <!-- want this -->
        <div value="2">
            <div itemprop="c" value="3" />
            <!-- and this -->
        </div>
        <div itemtype="d" itemscope="" itemprop="e" value="4">
            <!-- and even this -->
            <div itemprop="f" value="5" />
            <!-- but not this -->
            <div value="6" >
                <div itemprop="g" value="7" />
                <!-- nor this -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</root>
```

The XPath returns:

```
Attr    itemprop    b
Attr    itemprop    c
Attr    itemprop    e
```

Comment: this will work for the root itemscope but will fail when I try to apply the same xpath to get "d"'s  props... (what will be processed from with "d" as the context for the xpath)

Comment: Ok, so you actually want a "variable" root - not an actual document root. I'll take a look at it in few moments.

Comment: How are you performing the query? Depending if it is a part of a Java/C# app, or an XSLT transform there could be different solutions (due to for example different ways that the "root" or "context" can be declared. A simple way, if you can declare variables or perform string.replace would be: `//div[@value='root']//div[@itemprop and ancestor::div[@itemscope][1]/@value = 'root']/@itemprop` - setting `'root'` to for example '4' gives you `[f,g]`, but not subsequent children. Or maybe the root is always element with `value='root'`?